How to unbuffer output when using pipx?
I would like to tee the output of a Python script that I run with pipx run. Python buffers its output, so that tee doesn't flush the contents line by line to the TTY, but python -u would do the trick, because:

-u     : force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered;


However, this flag is not available on pipx or pipx run, but my script is called via pipx run to handle additional dependencies in a temporary virtual environment.
How can I tell pipx to flush the output line by line?

This question mentions an alternative with an environment that seems to do the trick:
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 pipx run myscript.py

Now tee correctly flushes stdout.
